# How can I open the desktop GUI on my virtual machine in Bluemix?

Tags: virtual-machine, vnc, ibm-cloud

I am running a virtual machine in Bluemix and want to open the OS's desktop GUI. How do I do this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need more information.  Are you following a set of steps and they're failing?  There's information in the link below that will assist you in getting started:

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/index-gentopic4.html

Comment: @Esteban Melendez: Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please mark it accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your question to what I think you're asking: How can I open the desktop GUI on my virtual machine in Bluemix?

Assuming I understand the question correctly:

To open the desktop GUI on a remote virtual machine, use Virtual Network Computing (VNC). This solution is not specific to Bluemix; it'll work with a VM running on any platform, as long as the VM is running an OS that supports VNC.

To use VNC, you need to have a VNC server running in your VM's OS. You will then run a VNC client (a.k.a. viewer) on your computer to display the VM's desktop. The specific instructions depend on the OS running in the VM and on your computer.

For example, assuming your VM is running Ubuntu v14.04, these resources explain what to do (and a search will find other resources):

- "[How to Install and Configure VNC on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)" -- Installs XFCE4 as the VNC server
- "[How To Install And Configure VNC On Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.unixmen.com/install-configure-vnc-ubuntu-14-04/)" -- Also installs XFCE4.
- "[How to Install VNC Server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-vnc-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)" -- Installs TightVNC as the VNC server

For a VNC client, I actually connect to remote VMs via a local VM running Ubutu 14.04, so I use [Vinagre](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC/Clients) (a.k.a. the Remote Desktop Viewer app). Options listed by other authors include TightVNC, RealVNC, or UltraVNC.

Good luck and thanks for using Bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need some remote desktop tool to get to the UI of the OS of your virtual machine. Some tools available: http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/applications/7-of-the-best-linux-remote-desktop-clients-716346